# how to select one row of a column of a table in org-mode (i.e. a cell of a table)

Tags: org-mode

in org-mode, is there a command to select the entire text in one column in one row? I know i can move to the beginning/set-mark/goto the end of the column. But i am wondering if there is one command already for that.

Comment: Cross-post of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41389604/selecting-the-text-in-a-column-and-row-in-org-mode  See "**Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?**":  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: The nearest i've found is `org-mark-element` (bound to `M-h`), which will select a whole row of a table.

Answer (score 2):

I asked the question in the org-mailing list. I was pointed to
this function which does what I needed: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2016-05/msg00240.html

```
 (defun org-table-mark-field ()
      "Mark the current table field."
      (interactive)
      ;; Do not try to jump to the beginning of field if the point is already there
      (when (not (looking-back "|\\s-?"))
        (org-table-beginning-of-field 1))
      (set-mark-command nil)
      (org-table-end-of-field 1))
```